# Big Bang Theory prop on Sheldon's bedroom wall

Tags: props, the-big-bang-theory

[*The Big Bang Theory*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0898266/) is full of interesting props. It's a pastime of mine to try to identify odd props in shows and movies.

This one has me stymied. It is in the rarely seen set of Sheldon's bedroom. I've seen it on at least two different episodes. Can anyone help?

[image: prop in Sheldon's bedroom]

Comment: Other than a first instinct that it looks like some kind of optical equipment, I've got no idea. Have you asked the same question on ChasingProps.com? They seem like they might have a better community for this question specifically.

Comment: I will guess laser or some sort of optical device

Comment: Could it be different generations of .. let's say radio tubes?

Comment: This appears in Season 1, episode 15, when Missy talks to Sheldon in his room.  I think an earlier episode too.

Answer (score 14):

It's distinctly reminiscent of a turn of the century morse code tapper (AKA a [telex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegraphy)), something like the one below;

[image]

Comment: To reinforce this:http://www.redorbit.com/media/uploads/2004/10/25_64652cdf870881e14485d7539934c5d2.jpg , http://www.saudervillage.org/Education/images/what_is_it/Telegraphy_02a.jpg , and other images on the image search page in google. Big +1 (Especially considering Sheldon is fluent in Morse Code).

Comment: Looks pretty close, but not exact. I'd go as far as to say you're showing us an updated version of the prop though.

Answer (score -2):

IMO, it looks more like a Klystron, so it should be some part of a Geiger counter or some other particle counter.

@OP , could you help me with the names of the two episodes where you saw this.
(I'm new so I can't put comments)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Movies & TV. Hope you have fun here, but unfortunately, since we're a question-and-answer website - not a run-of-the-mill chat forum - we prefer that you give more than a one-sentence answer, and that you provide backup and explanation for your answer (using picture references, sources, etc. where applicable and possible). If you could click on the "edit" button beneath your post & elaborate on your answer and why you came to that conclusion, that would be great. Thanks!